# How to retrieve the Link CSS Style class from the menu item parameters

Tags: css, parameters, hyperlink, styles, menuitem

I need to get the `"Link CSS Style" value` from the menu item parameters to use it within Ariextmenu to be able to style each link separately like when using the Joomla mo_menu.

I know I can use the numbered class of the Ariextmenu `"li"`, but this is not the best solution because when you edit the menu items the numbers change and the style given to that specific selector breaks up.
I have found a lot of threads dealing with getting the Page Class Sufix, but nothing about the Link CSS Style.

I am using `Joomla! 3.2.3`

Comment: Give us some code.. something to find out what you'r talking about. Also, please specify how you want to retieve that link and where you plan to use it. Could be easier to help if we know all that.

Comment: (Solved) Sorry for my mistake. I found that Ariextmenu writes a class with ordered numbers which not change when editing the menu items: ux-menu-item-parent-pos0, ux-menu-item-parent-pos1, etc. I didn't found the way to get the Link CSS Style values, but I don't need to. Using the class given by Ariextmenu is the correct way to style each link separately.

Comment: Thank you GMO! But I found another way, actually the right way.

Comment: Oh!.. I'm glad then... you could write it down as an answer and accepted as the correct one.. So if (in the case) someone came up with similar problem, could guide in your solution.